# Im looking for a way to add up elements of two arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, addition

i am looking for a way that i can add up elements in an array such that the first element of the first array is added to every element in the second array, then the second element in the first array is added to all every element in the second array and so on. The final vector will be length(a)*length(b) long

for example...

`a=[1,2,3,4] b=[5,6,7]
answer = 
    [(1+5),(1+6),(1+7),(2+5),(2+6),(2+7),(3+5),(3+6),(3+7),(4+5),(4+6),(4+7)]
   =[6,7,8,7,8,9,8,9,10,9,10,11]`

Comment: Have you tried? maybe a `for` loop? homework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first thought is to do this with arrayfun using an anonymous function that adds each scalar element of a to the full array in b. Then since you get a cell array result you can expand that cell array into the array you are looking for:

```
>> a=[1,2,3,4], b=[5,6,7]
>> result = arrayfun(@(x) x+b, a,'UniformOutput',false);
>> result = [result{:}]

result =

     6     7     8     7     8     9     8     9    10     9    10    11
```

Comment: @user3376766, this is certainly a correct solution, but don't make a habit of using `arrayfun`. For speed, see `bsxfun`.

Answer (score 5):

Read up on [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html). It's very useful for this kind of things (and usually faster than `arrayfun` or `for` loops):

```
result = bsxfun(@plus, a(:).', b(:)); %'// matrix of size numel(b) x numel(a)
result = result(:).'; %'// linearize to a vector
```

---

Or, a little more freak: [`kron`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/kron.html) does what you want with products instead of sums. So:

```
result = log(kron(exp(a),exp(b)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use meshgrid to create matrices of a and b and use matrix addition to compute a+b

```
a=[1,2,3,4], b=[5,6,7]

[A_matrix,B_matrix] = meshgrid(a,b)
result = A_matrix + B_matrix

result = result(:)'
```