# Add fixed number of increasing values after each element in matrix

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, I have a list of numbers `A` (a vector), and would need to add after each of the entries a number `n` of additional entries with values being 1 higher than the previous.

So let's say I have `A=[5 11 17]`, and n=1, I would need to make the resulting expression contain `[5 6 11 12 17 18]`.

How can I do that? I've seen `repmat` and Tony's Trick, but they only replicate a vector and don't add anything to the values. Is there any expression I can apply on a Matrix that e.g. the row index is added to each element's value?

Please excuse me if this is really a simple task, I'm really new to Matlab and haven't wrapped my head around all the concepts there yet I think... glad for any pointers!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22158727/im-looking-for-a-way-to-add-up-elements-of-two-arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the addition in two dimensions with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), and then [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html)  into a single row:

```
B = reshape(bsxfun(@plus, A, (0:n).'), 1, []); %'// A assumed to be a row vector
```

Example:

```
>> A = [5 11 17];
>> n = 2;
>> B = reshape(bsxfun(@plus, A, (0:n).'), 1, [])
B =
     5     6     7    11    12    13    17    18    19
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution myself in the meantime. Not sure on whether it's efficient, but I thought I'd post it anyway:

```
result = repmat(A, n-1, 1)+repmat([1:n-1]-1,length(A),1).'
result = result(:)
```

Comment: `bsxfun` is essentially `repmat` but more efficient

Comment: ok thanks! 1:n-1 is also not so brilliant... ;) I'm just getting used to *Matlab-think*, I'm a programmer so that's a bit hard ;)

Comment: Just for your info: Though `bsxfun` can often outperform `repmat`, `repmat` is not bad at all and doesn't need to be avoided.

Comment: @RandolphCarter Well, `repmat` is totally "Matlab-think" :-) As Dennis said, `bsxfun` is an improvement, but `repmat` is a typical Matlab (vectorized) construction